# How to set navigationcontroller push animation to "No" while using storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am using storyboard for a navigation based iphone application.
I want viewcontrollers to navigate using "pushviewcontroller" property but at the same time I dont want them to animate. Simply I want to set their Animation property to "NO"

How can I do this using storyboard?

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the answer by @azethoth creating a no animation segue is as easy as:

```
@interface NoAnimationSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
@end

@implementation NoAnimationSegue    
- (void)perform
{
    [[self.sourceViewController navigationController] pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
}    
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to do this declaratively. You would either manually call

```
[sourceController pushViewController:destination animated:NO];
```

Or, if you're hellbent on using the segue you could create your own subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue` and implement the `perform` method to do the above. Then in the storyboard you can use a Custom segue and put in the name of your segue subclass.

Comment: Note that custom segues behave like modal pushes and not like regular pushes, meaning you won't have Inferred Simulated Metrics in storyboard and since it's "modal" the presenting view controller view will go out of the viewstack and thus forget about transparency features.